# how to include javascript into web app projet in visual studio?

Tags: asp.net, javascript

Anyone knows how to include javascript file as project's resource for aspx.cs files under different folders to use?thanks very much

Comment: i have tried what rahul said before and tried to put js file in theme folder no luck

Comment: i  tried also
Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptInclude("FormScript",  Page.ResolveClientUrl("~/subfolder/myjs.js")); no luck

Comment: actually, i tried to have one place for embeding the js file, so i put the code in master page, just made minor error, the key for Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptInclude method is dulplicated , now it worked after i made each script with unique key .but thanks for all ur response.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose your project's directory looks like:

```
/App_Code
/App_Data
/App_Themes
/Master_Pages
...
web.config
```

Add a folder called "scripts" so you have:

```
/App_Code
/App_Data
/App_Themes
/Master_Pages
/scripts
...
web.config
```

Put your javascript file in this scripts folder.

Put the script tag in any of your aspx pages.

```
<script src="/ProjectRoot/scripts/your-file.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

The key to remember is the path you specify in the src attribute.  This is relative to the root of your domain.  If you are developing on your machine and you test your project at:
http://localhost:2430/SomeProject/

Then your script tag needs to look like:

```
<script src="/SomeProject/scripts/your-file.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

If your project is deployed on a server at the root: http://www.example.com/

Then your script tag needs to look like:

```
<script src="/scripts/your-file.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

If your project is deployed on a server at the root: http://www.example.com/SomeApp

Then your script tag needs to look like:

```
<script src="/SomeApp/scripts/your-file.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

FYI, because the script tag is not a server-side tag you can't use the "~/" syntax.  And because you can't use the "~/" syntax, you (usually) can't use a relative path for the src attribute but instead have to specify an absolute path from the root of your domain.

Comment: You can do `<script src="<%=VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/scripts/your-file.js")%>" type="text/javascript"></script>` to get the absolute path (if you're in an ASPX/ASCX/Master page).

Comment: A problem with this is you can't use code blocks inside master page header :(.  I think I'm gonna try using ASP.NET expressions e.g. <%$ AppSettings: BaseUrl %>

Answer (score 0):

Put the javascript file in a folder in the web application project.

In pages where you want to refer the javascript file you can add this in your aspx file.

```
<script src="path_to_yourfile" type="text/javascript"></script>
```